# Create region from set of lines and arcs

Tags: geometry, regions

I have a shape that is a knuckle plate with two holes cut in it, thus:

```
center1 = {0, 0};
center2 = {8, 0};
radius1 = 4;
radius2 = 3;
arc1 = Circle[center1, radius1, { -1 angle1, 2 \[Pi] + angle1}];
arc2 = Circle[center2, radius2, { -1 angle2, angle2}];
endpoint1 = {x1, y1};
endpoint2 = {x2, y2};
tangent = {endpoint1, endpoint2} /. 
   Solve[{(endpoint2 - center2).(endpoint2 - endpoint1) == 
      0, (endpoint1 - center1).(endpoint2 - endpoint1) == 
      0, (endpoint1 - center1).(endpoint1 - center1) == 
      radius1^2, (endpoint2 - center2).(endpoint2 - center2) == 
      radius2^2, (endpoint1 - center1).(endpoint2 - center2) > 
      0}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}, Reals];
angle1 = ArcTan[tangent[[1, 1, 2]]/tangent[[1, 1, 1]]];
angle2 = ArcTan[tangent[[2, 1, 2]]/tangent[[2, 1, 1]]];
bores = Circle[#, 1] & /@ {center1, center2};
Graphics[{arc1, arc2, Line[tangent], bores}]
```

[image: knuckle plate]

I want to be able create a region which is defined by the perimeter of the knuckle plate subtracted by the holes. I started to do this and ran into problems:

```
plate = RegionUnion[arc1, arc2, Line[tangent]];
platemesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[plate];
Graphics[{platemesh}]
```

This gives errors such as "There is not a boundary representation that uniquely defines a region with region dimension 1 embedded in dimension 2". (Note that I am hoping for a general answer that would work for any set of connected lines and arcs, not just a convex shape.)

**Note on potential duplicates:**

Solutions that involve ConvexHull are not applicable as explained above

Solution from a related post:

```
Polygon@points[[First@Rest@FindShortestTour@points]]
```

Involves flattening of the line segments into discrete points, which for a complex set of paths could be complicated. Ideally, I am looking for a solution that computes the region using the paths as the primary inputs without having to break those paths into more primitive objects.

Comment: It would seem to me that the answers you received and contributed yourself to [your very similar previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91499/27951) from yesterday should apply here as well.

Comment: @Tyler Durden: If the goal is to create a FEM mesh, then you can try the following.   In step `platemesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[plate]` instead of `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[plate]` use `DiscretizeRegion[plate]`. In the next step you can use either directly `ToElementMesh[]` included the option `MeshQualityGoal -> 0.1` or before that `ToBoundaryMesh[]`  and then build the element mesh.

Answer (score 3):

I am using all your definitions, except for bores, which I modified to use `Disk` instead of `Circle`:

```
bores = Disk[#, 1] & /@ {center1, center2};

RegionDifference[
 DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[
   Disk[center1, radius1],
   Disk[center2, radius2],
   Polygon[tangent[[1]]~Join~Reverse[tangent[[2]]]]
   ],
 DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion[bores]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This solves the immediate problem, but does not answer the question of how to create a region from a set of connected arcs and line segments.